# How to send JSON to Struts2 Action with AngularJS form?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, struts2

How to send JSON to Struts2 Action with AngularJS form?

My code:

My struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <action name="angularAction" class="actions.CustomerAction" method="findCustomer" >
        <result type="json">
              <param name="root">customer</param>
              <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
              <param name="noCache">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>

</package>
```

My Java Class:

```
public class Customer {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public Customer(String id, String name, String email, String phone) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;

    }

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

My Struts2 Action

```
public class ClienteAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Customer> jsonCustomer;

    public List<Customer> getJsonCustomer() {
        return jsonCustomer;
    }


    public void setJsonCustomer(List<Customer> jsonCustomer) {
        this.jsonCustomer = jsonCustomer;
    }

    public String findCustomer() {

        List<Customer> jc = getJsonCustomer();

        return SUCCESS;

    }

}
```

My Angular Code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').
controller('MyController',  function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDataFromServer = function(customer) {

        var data1 = JSON.stringify(customer);

            $http({
                url: 'angularAction?jasonCustomer=' + data1,
                method: 'GET'
            }).then (function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.customer = response.data;                    

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response.data) ;
            })      

        };
    });
```

[My Libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4K2u.png)

It doesn't work! The variable jsonCustomer in angularAction is null.

I'm newbie with angular. I'm using this tutorial, but angular instead jquery.

http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/

Thanks by help!

Comment: Use <s:url> to correctly mount struts urls. Also edit your question by specifying what doesn't work and how, then post error messages, stacktraces, javascript console errors etc. Also ensure you've correctly conffigured your interceptor stack and included all the libraries needed

Comment: Do you really want/need to send json?

Comment: Hi Aleksandr M, I'm newbie with angular. What does the best method to send form data to Struts Action?